# Solaris 11 login banner

Tags: solaris, login, gui

How do you add a (GUI) login banner in Solaris 11? I've done quite a bit of searching and have found many things on SSH and FTP banners/motd for remote logins, but not much for the local GUI login. I found a few things that mention editing `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` (mainly for Linux, nothing specifically Solaris). However, none of the suggested changes seem to affect the login screen. Is there something different you have to do to make this work in Solaris 11 or is it not possible?

Comment: After more searching, and many different combinations of keywords, I finally discovered some answers, in the Oracle Solaris 11 documentation, no less. I guess I'll post an answer here in hopes that it might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options for "login banner"-like behavior are presented in the [Securing the System](http://docs.huihoo.com/solaris/11/html/819-3195/conf-sec-mach-1.html#login-msg-2) section of the Oracle Solaris 11 Security Guidelines. The solution that does exactly what I was looking for is **Option 3**, which involves editing the actual GUI for the login screen using the GTK+ interface designer to add a label with the desired message.

A slightly less involved method that comes close is the first part of **Option 2**, which is to add the following code to `/etc/gdm/Init/Default`:

> ```
> /usr/bin/zenity --text-info --width=800 --height=300 \
> --title="Security Message" \
> --filename=/etc/issue
> ```

This will display a dialog box with the message before the login screen comes up. (**Note**: This assumes that your login banner text is contained in `/etc/issue`)

There are other options listed, but they all display the message *after* a user has entered login details.